# flatten array from single dimensional array

Tags: php

hi my array is like this

```
Array(['a1','aa1','1'],['a2','aa2','2'],['a3','aa3','3'],['a4','aa4','4'])
```

my required array

```
 Array(['a1','1'],['aa1',[1]],['a2','2'],['aa2','2'],['a3','3'],['aa3','3'],    
 ['a4','4'],['aa4','4'])
```

my requirement is i'll get the array with the combination of 1 & 3,2 & 3

please help me

Thank you

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: if u know answer help to others oterwise just get lost

Answer (score 1):

```
$b = array();
foreach ($a as $elem) {
    b[] = array($elem[0], $elem[2]);
    b[] = array($elem[1], $elem[2]);
}
```

Comment: @venkyMCA Please up vote this reply accept this as the correct answer.